# Get Split APK Info in Android

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I have a 3p appstore app which installs other apps. From my app, installing both single and split APKs are supported.

For apps with split APKs, during install time, I only install the required APKs like only the APK for the selected language on device.

Now when the device language changes, I want to install the new language APKs for all the apps which my app has installed. Before triggering install, I need to first check if that language APK is already installed or what all APKs are installed for a specific package name.

In Android, I didn't find any APIs which can give me if some language APK is installed or the info about all the installed APKs. Any way to get this info?

Edit-1: I cannot use Play core libraries. I am looking for a way using the classes from Android.

Comment: Kindly make it clear that do you want to get split info if the app is installed or you want to get info from a split file like xapk, apks etc which is not yet installed? Kindly let me know so i can add the answer for you. I have ways for both. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
Using the package names of the apps you have installed, you can get all the split APKs from PackageInfo.#applicationInfo but doesn't provide any additional info about that.

Playcore has some classes like SplitInstallManager which has methods getInstalledModules, getInstalledLanguages etc which can be used to get installed APKs but not sure if you can get info about other apps too.

Answer (score 0):

### Code:

```
public static boolean isConfigInstalled(PackageManager pm, String pkg, String conf) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
{
    // get application info for installed app
    ApplicationInfo ai=pm.getApplicationInfo(pkg, 0);
    
    // get installed split's Names
    String[] sn=ai.splitNames;

    // check whether if it's really split or not
    if (sn != null && sn.length > 0)
    {
        // search installed splits
        for(String n:sn){
            // check whether is the one required
            if(n.equals("config." + conf)){
                // yes, it's installed!
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    // couldn't find!
    return false;
}
```

### How to use:

*Just pass the package manager that you get by *context.getPackageManager()* along with the *App's package name* and the *language code**

### Example:

```
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
        String pkg="com.snapchat.android";
        String languageCode="ur";
        if(isConfigInstalled(pm, pkg, languageCode)){
            System.out.println("Snapchat has Urdu Installed!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Snapchat doesn't has Urdu Installed!");
        }
```

### Output:

```
    Snapchat has Urdu Installed!
```